# woocommerce order details dashboard custom text

Tags: woocommerce

I am currently using this to add extra information on the order page details. it is working perfect however i want to move it to be under the box where u add notes to customers.

Want the "fast responses" to be under the add note box ( as seen on the picture ), so i can just copy the responses fast when i need them to send to customers. either like that or in a box under it. but i cant find any hooks to talk to the order notes, or after order notes.

```
// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Fast responses' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( '2 parcel shipment' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'You incorrect address' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Your payment failed' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a meta box under the order notes then print your response in it.

try out this code.

```
 // Adding Meta container admin shop_order pages
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'zillion_add_meta_boxes');
if (!function_exists('zillion_add_meta_boxes')) {
    function zillion_add_meta_boxes()
    {
        add_meta_box('zillion_other_fields', __('My Response', 'woocommerce'), 'zillion_add_other_fields_for_packaging', 'shop_order', 'side', 'core');
    }
}

// Adding Meta field in the meta container admin shop_order pages
if (!function_exists('zillion_add_other_fields_for_packaging')) {
    function zillion_add_other_fields_for_packaging()
    { 
        global $post;
        ?>
        <div class="order_data_column">
            <h4><?php _e('Fast responses'); ?></h4>
            <?php
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('2 parcel shipment') . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta($post->id, '_some_field', true) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('You incorrect adress') . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta($post->id, '_another_field', true) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('Your payment failed') . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta($post->id, '_another_field', true) . '</p>'; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```